Is it possible to give an existing Flatpak application permission to run another Flatpak?
You can give a Flatpak permissions to access files/folders outside of its sandbox using the techniques described in this Ubuntu Stack Exchange QA.
But is it possible to give an existing Flatpak application permission to run another Flatpak application?
The catch here (which is a bit of a Catch-22) is that to run a Flatpak application, the flatpak executable needs to be run, and it is typically located in /bin or /usr/bin.  And /bin is reserved path, according to the Flatpak documentation.  Thus, a Flatpak application cannot call flatpak itself unless it is stored somewhere atypical, which could, in theory, violate the effectiveness of its sandboxing functionality.
So is it possible or impossible to give an existing Flatpak application permission to run another Flatpak application?

You can use flatpak-spawn(1) with the --host option. Excerpt from the man page:
DESCRIPTION
       Unlike other flatpak commands, flatpak-spawn is available to
       applications inside the sandbox. It runs COMMAND outside the sandbox:
       either in another sandbox, or on the host.
[...]
       --host
           Run the command unsandboxed on the host. This requires access
           to the org.freedesktop.Flatpak D-Bus interface.

